# React.js - Separate the JSON return with pagination

Tags: json, reactjs, pagination

I have this component below and it is working fine. But I would like to insert pagination on the items returned by JSON, like 6 photos for each page. How can I solve it ? Thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const URL_HOUSES = 'http://localhost:3001/houses';

class Houses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    houses: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(URL_HOUSES)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ houses: res.data })
    })
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.houses.map(item =>             
          <ul>
            {
              item.photos.map(photo => <li>{photo}</li>)
            }
          </ul>           
      )}
     </div>
   )
 }
}

 export default Houses;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const URL_HOUSES = 'http://localhost:3001/houses';

class Houses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    houses: [],
    currentPage: 1 //On Page change event increment this
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(URL_HOUSES)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ houses: res.data })
    })
  }

render() {
  var pageEnd = this.state.currentPage * 6;
  var pageStart = pageEnd - 6

  return (
    <div>
        //slice the array based on the current page
      {this.state.houses.slice(pageStart, pageEnd - 1).map(item =>             
          <ul>
            {
              item.photos.map(photo => <li>{photo}</li>)
            }
          </ul>           
      )}
     </div>
   )
 }
}

 export default Houses;
```

May be syntactically incorrect and lacks a few checks, but I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Houses extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        houses: [],
        pageSize: 6,
        currentPage: 1,
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(URL_HOUSES)
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ houses: res.data })
        })
      }

    render() {
     const { houses,pageSize, currentPage } = this.state
     const pageNo = Math.floor(houses.length / pageSize)
     const housesToDisplay = houses.slice((pageNo-1) * pageSize, ((pageNo-1) * pageSize) + pageSize))
      return (
        <div>
          {housesToDisplay.map(item =>             
              <ul>
                {
                  item.photos.map(photo => <li>{photo}</li>)
                }
              </ul>           
          )}
         </div>
       )
     }
    }

     export default Houses;
```

So above implementation is the basic implementation . it may have some edge cases , that you need to take care. And one moe thing , you need to add buttons for pagination and attach event handlers to button which which will update currentPage in react state. Idea is generic. You can read the code and understand . If any queries , do let me know